# How can I get the followers count of users in Facebook using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting the facebook page based fan_count details only, but I want the followers count of a user using graph api

Answer (score 0):

> but I want the followers count of a user using graph api

You can not get that, the API does not expose this information.

Answer (score 0):

This is deprecated from from Facebook graph API

you can refer this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/275153803394034/) for more info.